# In Python 3.0 a function returns none because a function does not store it’s output unless we use a return statement?

Tags: python, return, return-value

In Python, does a function just execute it’s code block & not store it unless we use a return statement?

When we print variables & expressions I understand we are printing values.

So I am thinking that a function performs it’s code block & then does not save that result unless we return it? Is this what’s happening in the computer?

```
 Example 1  
def add(a,b):
 nums = a + b

print(add(2,4)+2)
Error
```

But when we use the return value statement it works

```
 Example 2
def add(a,b):
 nums = a + b
 return nums

print(add(2,4) + 2)
Output: 8
```

The error was caused in the first example because the function just executed it’s code block & did not save the result therefore resulting in an error due to not being able to add None to an integer(2)?
&
It worked in example 2 because we saved the functions result with the return statement giving us an integer; Therefore allowing the print statement to print the result of the functions integer + the integer we added it to in the expression?

Comment: In Python, variables have function scope/life. All variables in the function are stored (returning or not). When the function ends or returns, all variables in that function are deleted (unless they are global)

Comment: When the function ends does the result of that function terminate/not get saved & to store/save it we use the return statement?

Comment: When a variable leaves scope, its value is lost unless you do something to make it be stored somewhere else. There are lots of different ways to save your values somewhere else (copying them to a global, or sending them over a channel, or so on or so forth), so it's not really accurate or useful to say that all values that aren't returned are destroyed; there are other ways to preserve a value other than returning it, but often returning it is the most appropriate choice.

Comment: To save the returned value use `value = function_that_returns()`

Comment: Appreciate the help guys, I apologize if my knowledge gap has been frustrating.

Comment: ...so, to try to explain something that's been bugging me about how this question is phrased: `return`ing a value puts a copy of that value on the stack where whatever called the function can read it, _but it doesn't actually stop the local variable from being destroyed_. The local variable is _always_ destroyed when it exits scope, no matter if a copy of (or reference to) the value that local previously pointed to was returned or not. (The memory storing the value won't be freed as long as there's at least one reference to it, but the local is no longer there to be such a reference).

Comment: ...so one thing that's problematic about saying that returning a value "saves" that value is that it doesn't, really: it gives the caller an opportunity to save the value, but if the caller doesn't choose to do so, the value is lost _even if you did use `return`_. (When you run something at the Python REPL, it automatically prints your values as part of its behavior as a _Read, Eval, Print Loop_; but in regular Python code as opposed to a REPL that behavior doesn't exist, so it's best not to make it part of your mental model).

Comment: (apologies if this is hard to follow; I prefer to teach in-person with a whiteboard or scratch paper at hand when there's a chance to get feedback and adjust pace or sidebar to explain missing concepts; it's tricky to know what the shared foundation is with this kind of low-bandwidth channel)

Comment: I really don’t know how to thank you, this is the information I was seeking to understand.

Comment: when we call a function & it performs it’s calculations
1: it stores it’s results on a stack frame in a stack
2: then returns to the caller the result when we use the return statement?

Answer (score 0):

In python, functions are blocks of code that execute some logic of some sort (sometimes based on arguments passed into them and sometimes not). They are very broad and can do many different kinds of things depending on how they are constructed. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "store the results" but hopefully some of the following explanation will help. 
All variables created in a function are stored with the "local" scope, meaning that they are only existent when the function is running and are deleted the moment the function terminates. For example, in the following code, you cannot access the variable `x` after the function terminates:

```
def example():
    x = 'Hello World'
    print(x) #This prints: Hello World
example()
print(x) #This will give you a Reference error
```

If that is what you mean by "stores the results" then you are right: those results will not be stored. You can, however, declare a variable inside of a function to be a global variable, meaning that it can be accessed outside of the function too:

```
def example():
    global x = 'Hello World'
    print(x) #This prints: Hello World
example()
print(x) #This prints: Hello World
```

When you use the `return` statement in a function you are just telling the compiler that if a variable is set equal to a function call of said function, whatever follows the return statement is what that variable should be set equal to. However, simply returning a value does not "store" it. See the following code:

```
def example():
    x = 'Hello World'
    return x
example()
print(x) #This will still cause a reference error
x = example()
print(x) #This prints: Hello World
```

One final thing to note about the code above: as long as two variables are in different scopes, they can have the same name and not cause an error. The `x` inside the function is in a local scope and the `x` outside of the function is in the global scope which is why that does not cause an error.

Comment: This was helpful, appreciate it. Still a little confused as to why functions needs a return statement, as in why does a function return None instead of the output it produces unless we add the return value statment?

Comment: @river, what do you mean by "the output it produces"? Functions don't produce output by default. In `def add(a,b): nums = a + b`, nothing is producing any output at all. _Most_ means of producing output are what are called a "side effect" -- like printing a value, or sending it over a network, or so forth; producing side effects doesn't modify your return value.

Comment: (a smarter language would have the compiler notice that `nums` is never being used and not even bother doing the work to calculate it)

Comment: @river I think that you are struggling a bit with a conceptual misunderstanding with what exactly output is. Output, in the world of programing, *literally* refers to whatever follows the return statement of a function. Without a return statement, there *is* no output. Functions are only meant to do two things: produce side effects, as Charles Duffy mentioned,  like printing values or sometimes creating/editing variables in the global scope, and returning values. Everything else in a function that does not do one of these things should only there to assist in getting to a point where it can.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. When I was learning programming, it helped me to think of calls to functions using an analogy to variables in math. In most languages, you can think of "substituting" the `return` value in for the function call, the same way you can substitute a literal number into a variable.

In math, you can do this:

```
m = 4
b = 2

y = m * x + b  # Plug 4 and 2 in for "m" and "b"
y = 4 * x + 2
```

It's the same with value-returning functions:

```
def foo():
    return 'bar'
```

```
>>> x = foo() # Plug the return value 'bar' in for "foo()"
>>> x
'bar'
```

In Python, when a function has no explicit `return`, the default return value is `None`. So:

```
def foo():
    print('bar')
    # No return, so Python implicitly returns None
```

```
>>> x = foo() # Plug the return value None in for "foo()"
'bar'
>>> x
None
```

Comment: Hey Jackson, appreciate the response. I see though, in the second last example, when calling the function it would print ‘bar’ in the console.

Comment: @river, correct, `print('bar')` does print `bar` in the console, but it does that _as a side effect_; the return value is still `None`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is right. Notice that Python makes the "substitution" when the function call is executed: on the line `x = foo()`, the right side of the `=` must be evaluated (to have something to set `x` to), so `foo()` is executed, which prints `bar`. But the return value is still `None`, so printing `x` itself gives `None`.

Answer (score -1):

the function define local variable even same name as global variable so when it executed if you don't return something or store the result in global variable the result not appears outside function
example

```
x = 10
def test():
   x= 15
test()
print(x) # result 10
```

but if use global keyword you can access to global variable like this

```
x = 10
def test():
   global x
   x= 15
test() 
print(x) #result 15
```

or if you return the value

```
x = 10
def test():
  x= 15
  return x
x = test()
print(x) #result 15
```

Comment: That’s not what the OP meant and wanted to know

Comment: Thank you Omar, my question is more of what happens to the result/output of a function when the function ends? Does the result of that function terminate/not get saved & to store/save it we use the return statement?

Comment: @river, `return` doesn't "save" anything on its own; it just, well, _returns_ the value to the caller, and its caller can save (or otherwise do something with) that value if it chooses.

Comment: river When the end of the scope your  function variable is deallocated. This means the memory used by your variable is released.

Comment: @river, ...this is a place where it might be helpful to spend a little bit of time with a simpler stack-based programming language to see what's going on under the hood. Anyone who dealt with a 1980s calculator may know RPN, or for folks looking for a modern game-centric experience, TIS-100 by Zachtronics is a great game built around a stack machine that teaches these concepts. Really, any assembly language will introduce you to the idea of a stack machine (and thus, stack-based calling conventions); but the easiest ones to get started with are mostly toy machines embedded in games these days.